# Jaxb - Allow serialize/deserialize for messages containing deifferent namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an application that handles message in xml format, the message is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cmn:command xmlns:cmn="https://www.example.com/uri/xmlns/common/1/4">
    <cmn:context>
        <cmn:id>2a14598b-23d8-402f-8c18-fa450152f8aa</cmn:id>
    </cmn:context>
    <cmn:body>
        <not:notifyUser xmlns:not="https://www.example.com/uri/xmlns/notification/1/3" version="1.3.0">
            <not:userId>0114598b-23d8-402f-8c18-de450152f8aa</not:userId>
        </not:notifyUser>
    </cmn:body>
</cmn:command>
```

The application is changed frequently, hence the namespaces that are loaded into it usually have greater "version" than the incoming message. In this case, the application may have these namespaces which are different than the example message:

```
xmlns:cmn="https://www.services.zh.ch/uri/xmlns/zhs-common/1/5"
xmlns:not="https://www.example.com/uri/xmlns/notification/1/4"
```

The messages come from external systems and the requirement is avoid making them to update  their namespaces as much as possible. So the application must be able to:

1. Deserialize the message even if the namespaces are different, it still throws error if the message is not align with the namespaces in the application. (containing removed fields, missing required fields etc...). In short, treat the incoming message's namespaces as they are the same as the current ones in the application and try to validate and deserialize it.
2. Serialize the result to the same namespace as the incoming message. E,g: if the message has namespace "np-v1/0", the application has "np-v1/1", the output message must have namespace "np-v1/0"

Currently, we are patching the messages using regex and string replacement to the desired namespaces before serializing/deserializing which is turning in to problem now because we are having more namespaces to work on.

Is there a better way to do it?